# What are the meaning of these sentences? Christiani victores obsessi

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin, translation-explanation

I am trying to translate the chapter titles of four chapters in a medieval source, Caffaro's *De Liberatione Civitatum Orientis*. Here is the full table of contents:

[image: index capitulorum]

Here are the four chapters I wish to translate:

- VI. Christiani victores obsessi.
- XXI. Enumeratio civitatum persequitur.
- XXII. Praelium navale Genuensium contra Graecos.
- XXV. Genuenses apud Laodiciam hiemantur.

What is the meaning of these chapter titles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a literal translation of the four chapter titles:

> Christiani victores obsessi

**The Christian victors [are] besieged**

N.B. "obsessi" is the past participle of [*obsideo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dobsideo).

> Enumeratio civitatum persequitur

**The enumeration of cities continues**

Without context, this is harder to understand: I presume that a previous chapter began listing cities and this chapter continues it.

> Praelium navale Genuensium contra Graecos

**The naval battle of the Genoese against the Greeks**

> Genuenses apud Laodiciam hiemantur

**The Genoese winter [i.e. set up winter quarters] in Laodicea**

Comment: thank you for your help.